# How to sign Windows Store App?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I just completed my windows 8.1 app and now I want to put it in the store. This is my first app publishing in the store so I want to know that how can I sign my app using self sign certificate.
I referred  various Msdn articles but they points to signing certificate for that apps that are going to be sideloaded.

Currently I am using Test certificate which can be generated from app manifest file packaging tab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to - Store-submitted apps are signed by the Store itself.

Comment: Do I need to remove test certificate currently I am using or Store will automatically replace it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  Just submit the app to the Store.

Comment: What if you're not submitting the app to the store? and hope to sideload the app?